# Reading line current and line voltage with PAC1934 IC

Tags: voltage, integrated-circuit, current-measurement, voltage-measurement

I want to read the voltage and current at the output of the line with the PAC1934 IC. It is stated that the breakdown limit is 40V, but when I give a voltage over 32V on this line, I cannot view it and there is an underlined phrase in the datasheet Page 3. What does it mean? How can I read a voltage above 32 volts with this IC? When I want to read voltage directly from any sense pin, I cannot see above 32 volts. On the test board I prepared, I want to give a voltage over 32 volts and read it from the sense terminals, but even when I give a value over 32 volts, I see 32 volts.

[image: Datasheet Page 3]

[Datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PAC1931-Family-Data-Sheet-DS20005850E.pdf)

Comment: What page of the DS? What "output of the line"? What circuit?

Answer (score 1):

The **common mode voltage range** of the chip sense inputs is given as 0 to +32 volts. It can only read voltages within that range (-0.2V but not tested for that).

It won't destroy it to go as high as 40V if Vcc is applied (32V if Vcc is not applied) but that doesn't mean it will function properly.

Comment: When I read that the IC can withstand up to 40 volts when Vdd is connected, I thought I could see over 32 volts at the output. Now I understand that when I give over 32 volts, the integrated does not break, but I can read a maximum of 32 volts at the output. Is it correct? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's exactly correct.